# EventListener not toggling as expected to

Tags: javascript, html, css, event-handling

I'd like my code to display the "i" element which contains a font awesome icon  only when the user clicks on the button. Hence the event listener. The css rule I've set is "display: none". Then in my javascript file I've written the line of code 'document.getElementById("icon").style.display = "block"' so as to make the element in question visible when the user clicks on the button. However, the element is always visible, regardless of the user clicking on the button or not. I used classList.toggle() but without success either. If someone could fix my code that would be great.

```js
const name = document.getElementById("name");
const image = document.getElementById("image");
var personPaying = ""
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const people = ["pierre", "paul", "jacques", "henry" ];
const date = new Date().getDay();
const daysOfWeek = Array.from({length: 7}, (item, i) => {
  return new Date(0,0,i).toLocaleDateString("en-US", {weekday: "long"})
})
var today = daysOfWeek[date];

var names = {
  "Monday": "emilie",
  "Tuesday": "emilie",
  "Wednesday": "jessica",
  "Thursday": "jessica",
  "Friday": "paul",
  "Saturday": "paul",
  "Sunday": "pierre",
}

console.log(names[today])

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  date >= 0 && date < 2 ? personPaying = `today is ${today} so ${names[today]} is footing the bill`
  : date >= 2 && date < 4 ? personPaying = `today is ${today} ${names[today]} is paying`
  : date >= 4 && date < 6 ?   personPaying = `Hi ${names[today]}, today is ${today} so although we are in Amsterdam we're not going ducth`
  : personPaying = `Hi ${names[today]}, today is ${today}, your turn to pay today`
  name.textContent = personPaying;
  image.src = `picture/${names[today]}.png`
  image.alt = "picture of an avatar"
  document.getElementById("icon").style.display = "block";

}, false)
```

```css
.center {
  margin: 100px 50px 75px 100px;
  /* border: 3px solid green; */
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: medium;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  font-family: "Copperplate", "Papyrus", "fantasy";
  font-size: 50px;
  font-variant: "small-caps";
}


button {
  box-shadow: 5px 10px;
  font-family: 'Krona One', "sans-serif";
  /* font-family: "Copperplate", "Papyrus", "fantasy"; */
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: light;
  margin: 100px 200px 75px 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;

}

button:hover {
  font-family: "fantasy";
  box-shadow: inherit;
}

body {
background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right top;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: auto;
}

.unseen {display: none;
}

img {
  box-shadow: 5px 10px;
  width: 30%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Who's buying today</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Krona+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2da085e01f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="name" class="center"></div>
    <button id="btn" type="submit">who's paying</button>
    <img id="image" src="">
    <i id="icon" class="far fa-money-bill-alt unseen"></i>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things as working as expected. Your CSS is getting over-written by the external CSS that is getting downloaded.

Increase the specificity of `.unseen` CSS class to make it work.

```
i.unseen {
   display: none
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the class does not toggle once assigned. I think fontawesome is messes with the classlist for some reasons

Comment: for me, the `classList.toggle("unseen")` is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If the element refuses to toggle it's class, toggle the class on its parents and the child will comply

Here `<i>` refuses to toggle .unseen for some reasons but you can always wrap a parent around it that you can toggle `.unseen` with.

example: `<span class="unseen"><i></span>`

This way `<i>` will disappear along its parent. And when you toggle `.unseen`, it will appear again and vice-versa

```js
const name = document.getElementById("name");
const image = document.getElementById("image");
var personPaying = ""
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const people = ["pierre", "paul", "jacques", "henry"];
const date = new Date().getDay();
const daysOfWeek = Array.from({
  length: 7
}, (item, i) => {
  return new Date(0, 0, i).toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
    weekday: "long"
  })
})
var today = daysOfWeek[date];

var names = {
  "Monday": "emilie",
  "Tuesday": "emilie",
  "Wednesday": "jessica",
  "Thursday": "jessica",
  "Friday": "paul",
  "Saturday": "paul",
  "Sunday": "pierre",
}

console.log(names[today])

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  date >= 0 && date < 2 ? personPaying = `today is ${today} so ${names[today]} is footing the bill` :
    date >= 2 && date < 4 ? personPaying = `today is ${today} ${names[today]} is paying` :
    date >= 4 && date < 6 ? personPaying = `Hi ${names[today]}, today is ${today} so although we are in Amsterdam we're not going ducth` :
    personPaying = `Hi ${names[today]}, today is ${today}, your turn to pay today`
  name.textContent = personPaying;
  image.src = `picture/${names[today]}.png`
  image.alt = "picture of an avatar"
  document.getElementById("icon").classList.toggle("unseen");

}, false)
```

```css
.center {
  margin: 100px 50px 75px 100px;
  /* border: 3px solid green; */
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: medium;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  font-family: "Copperplate", "Papyrus", "fantasy";
  font-size: 50px;
  font-variant: "small-caps";
}
i{
font-size:3rem;
}
button {
  box-shadow: 5px 10px;
  font-family: 'Krona One', "sans-serif";
  /* font-family: "Copperplate", "Papyrus", "fantasy"; */
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: light;
  margin: 100px 200px 75px 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

button:hover {
  font-family: "fantasy";
  box-shadow: inherit;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right top;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: auto;
}

.unseen {
  display: none;
}

img {
  box-shadow: 5px 10px;
  width: 30%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Who's buying today</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Krona+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2da085e01f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



</head>

<body>
  <div id="name" class="center"></div>
  <button id="btn" type="submit">who's paying</button>
  <img id="image" src="">
  <span id="icon" class="unseen"><i class="far fa-money-bill-alt"></i><span>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```